# Realtime validation of Email with ajax and laravel(if email is already in database, it says email taken) like in gmail registration page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, validation

My Laravel controller class which checks if the email is already stored in the database or not: In my User table, it checks for if email exists in the database or not?

```
public function checkemail(){
      $userCount = DB::table('users')->where('email', input::get('email'));
      if($userCount->count()) 
      {
          return Response::json(array('msg' => 'true'));
      }
      else 
      {
       return Response::json(array('msg' => 'true'));
      }
}
```

My Ajax method which checks if email is already stored in database or not?
If it is stored in database then it should say email address already taken or else nothing. If email is taken, it shows in red line and if not then nothing.
The form name is registration.
url in web.php is

```
routes::post('checkmail','postcontroller@checkmail');
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#registration").validate({

    errorElement: 'div',
    errorLabelContainer: '.errorTxt',
    ignore: [],

    //following rules for email
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            remote: {

                url: "checkemail",
                type: "post",
                data: {
                    email: $("input[email='email']").val()
                },
                dataFilter: function(data) {
                    var json = JSON.parse(data);
                    if (json.msg == "true") {
                        return "\"" + "Email address already in use" + "\"";
                    } else {
                        return 'true';
                    }
                }
            }
        },

    },
    messages: {
        email: {
            required: 'Email is required',
            email: 'Please enter a valid email address',
            remote: 'Email already taken'
        }


    },

    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if (element.attr("name") == "email") {
            $(".erroremail").append(error);
        } else {
            error.append($('.errorTxt span'));
        }
    },


    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();

    }


});
```

Can anyone help me please, I am quite new to Laravel and ajax as a whole.

Comment: why do you validate form using jQuery plugin, there is functionality of server side [validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation) in Laravel

Comment: I want real time validation using ajax and laravel to check if email exists already in database without clicking submit button. I have already implemented server side in laravel.

Comment: Okay, let me find code for you.

Comment: I think the best way for real-time validation is: [laravel-jsvalidation](https://github.com/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Textbox blur event

```
<input type="text" name="email" onblur="duplicateEmail(this)" class="form-control">
```

**jQuery function**

```
  function duplicateEmail(element){
        var email = $(element).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '{{url('checkemail')}}',
            data: {email:email},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(res) {
                if(res.exists){
                    alert('true');
                }else{
                    alert('false');
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {

            }
        });
    }
```

**route**

```
Route::post('/checkemail',['uses'=>'PagesController@checkEmail']);
```

**controller**

```
public function checkEmail(Request $request){
    $email = $request->input('email');
    $isExists = \App\User::where('email',$email)->first();
    if($isExists){
        return response()->json(array("exists" => true));
    }else{
        return response()->json(array("exists" => false));
    }
}
```

you can add your AJAX success handler code, based on `true` & `false`

Comment: customerRegistrationForm:230 Uncaught ReferenceError: duplicateEmail is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onblur (customerRegistrationForm:230)
onblur @ customerRegistrationForm:230

Comment: have you added jQuery `duplicateEmail` function in your code?

Comment: yes I have done. it als0 says POST 500 internal server error

Comment: yeah I have added in <srcript></script> in my blad.php folder where my form is there. I error of uncaught reference is gone but now I have Internal server 500 post error

Comment: Hi I figured out the problem its because of the x-csrf-token. But it always return true whatever the email address is?

Comment: Hi one more question? why does it return true everytime? whatever the email is.

Comment: it will not return true everytime, if email is already there in table then only it will return true

Answer (score 2):

In the controller:

```
$this->validate(request()->all(), function () {
    return [
        'email' => 'unique:users'
    ];
});
```

Now if the email exists in your database, it will return with an array and then the validation message at the index of the name with a `422` error, which you can catch in the `fail` callback of your ajax request;

```
$.ajax({

}).done(function(resp){
    //successful
}).fail(function(errors) {
    // use errors to get the error message
});
```

In this way, because the server will respond with a `422` error code, if there's a failure on the email it will always hit `.fail()` and you won't have to worry about doing `if()` conditionals in your `.done()` method.

Now you can implement your `ajax` call in the `onblur` method of your email input:

```
$('input[type="email"]').on('blur', function(e) {
     // $.ajax stuff goes here
});
```